Are there any well known recordings that use the "Piano + Strings" sound?
Lots of domestic and professional keyboard instruments have a "piano layered with strings" sound. I'm sure these help sell keyboards as they sound nice, but are there any well-known recordings that use the sound? I'm wondering how musically useful the sound is...

I suggest changing the question to ask what contexts or styles the sound is typically used in, to avoid the question being closed.

That's a good question, Brian THOMAS.
Come to think of it, a lot of Yamaha & Casio keyboards have that "piano layered with strings" voicing, but I cannot name a single hit song that employs those patches.

I'll just leave this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCCan3TFPoc. It's not strictly using the "piano layered with strings" sound but if you need to play it with single keyboard, that sound is the closest thing.

I wouldn’t be surprised if it’s been done but piano/strings patches are used much more for live performances when a fuller sound is desired on certain songs like ballads. If you’re in a recording studio you have the luxury of creating independent string parts, even if with a keyboard. That gives you more versatility and also flexibility when mixing.

“Dreams” by Van Halen and I’m sure many other 80s songs.

I would look into live Bruce Hornsby concert recordings.
Back in the day when it was a new thing, Hornsby routinely used a MIDI'd grand piano to drive a sampler playing strings as a second layer during solo piano sections of his performances.  My recollection is that the strings had little velocity control, sitting at mezzo-piano, such that loud piano passages obscured them, and then they would suddenly be noticed during softer passages.
I'd bet a nickel that almost all piano+string patches have their historical roots in Hornsby.

Here's a nickel for The End of the Innocence.  Around minute 2:02 I hear the layered strings behind the piano notes placed by Bruce Hornsby while we see (from the wide angle shot) that the 2 violins + cello + keyboard + Hammond keyboard + synthesizer are not playing.
